# Don't want user to have playback control using MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: xcode, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios5.1

I am wanting to remove/hide playback buttons so that the user can not control playback. Is this possible in MPMoviePlayerController?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove all the control buttons from the `MPMoviePlayerController` using the `controlStyle` property:

```
playerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

Comment: @yellahd you should up vote and accept this answer then - see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).